# Showing PHP Scripts

Tags: php, html, css, apache

i have a site on which i made a sub-domain that allows developer to look at my php scripts but instead of making the browser reads it.. I want it to display the source here is my site: docs.bukkitpe.net  . So am asking is there any php scripts or line of code or even using .htaccess to display php from excuting the script but instead show it?

ALSO: If you do know how

How do i add it to all files, Cause i have over 250 php scrips (Including some folders) is there a way i can apply that to all scripts without having to modify all scripts which would take me alot of time?? Also i want 2 files to be ignored which is index.php and a folder name called resources

Comment: if you use &lt;?php instead of <php, PHP will not execute the code.

Comment: you can make a code to print raw your php code, or to print with some colors in certains functions, that will be the best idea, that will allow you to make it more beautiful with 10 minutes of your work

Comment: Use `show_source()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.show-source.php